# Howto submit a form with Angular and displaying results on a different page

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm trying to submit a form from a HTML page using angular. 
My HTML code is:

```
<form role="search">
<input type="text" ng-model="searchSring">
<button type="submit" ng-click="searchPerson(searchString);">Get it!
</button>
</form>
```

The searchPerson function is calling some PHP page using Ajax and data is successfully retrieved from it.

What I want is when the user has clicked the Get it! button, he should be routed to another HTML page where I would like to display the results. I've tried using "action=" in the form and even calling window.location once Ajax completed to route to the next page. Every time the result is cleared. I've tried using factory with get/set, but this too clears the data on the second page after the window.location call.
Here's the factory code:

```
myApp.factory('searchService', function(){

var searchService = {};
var mySearchResult = {};

    searchService.set = function(searchResult){
        mySearchResult = searchResult;
    }

    searchService.get = function(text){
        return mySearchResult;
    }                 
return searchService;
```

});

**CONTROLLER**

```
myApp.controller('OnlineCVController', function($scope, searchService) {
$scope.searchPerson = function(personString) {
$.ajax({
      url: "mySearch.php", 
      type: 'POST', 
      data: { Person: personString }, 
      async: false, success: function (result) { searchService.set(result);
 console.log(result); 
 window.location = "search.html"; 
       }, error: function (result) { } }); 
 }
```

Can anyone guide me further?

Comment: typo in HTML <input ... ng-model="searchSring"> ? should be ng-model="searchString" I guess.

Comment: what about your controller

Comment: myApp.controller('OnlineCVController', function($scope, searchService) {

$scope.searchPerson = function(personString)
{
   $.ajax({
        url: "mySearch.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { Person: personString },
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
     searchService.set(result);
  console.log(result);
     window.location = "search.html";
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
}

Comment: are you using `$stateProvider` ?

Comment: When you use window.location to change your location, you're causing your current page to get unloaded, and the new page to load up, with an all new copy of angular.  Study up on the routing module.